# How can i set the index for the slug category?

Tags: wordpress, categories, slug

I want to create a index page for the slug category . I mean if i go to http://www.mywebsite.com/category/nameofthecategory it will display the informations of the category, it's fine . But if i go to http://www.mywebsite.com/category/ i'm redirected to the home page .
How can i put or create the file index ? for the slug category ?

I will have to put some in category.php in my theme ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating a page via WP admin called 'Category' with the slug `category`?

Comment: Sorry, i fixed it, i had to create the page with the good slug then create a template sorry for my silly question ^^